# object type private class members

Tags: c++

Both bounding box and cube take a few arguments in their constructor

Header:

```
#ifndef WALL_H
#define WALL_H

#include "cube.h"
#include "BoundingBox.h"

class Wall
{
    private:
        Cube* cube;
        BoundingBox* boundingBox;
    public:
        Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max);
        ~Wall();
        void Draw(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection);
};

#endif
```

Source:

```
#include "Wall.h"

Wall::Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max)
{
    cube = new Cube(D3DXCOLOR(255, 20, 20, 255), min, max);
    boundingBox = new BoundingBox(min, max);
}

void Wall::Draw(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection)
{
    cube->Draw(matView, matProjection);
}

Wall::~Wall()
{
    delete cube;
    delete boundingBox;
}
```

My question is, how would I modify these classes so that cube and boundingBox are not pointers but simply instances? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple. Just like this:

```
#ifndef WALL_H
#define WALL_H

#include "cube.h"
#include "BoundingBox.h"

class Wall
{
private:
Cube cube;
BoundingBox boundingBox;
public:
Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max);
void Draw(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection);
};

#endif
```

source:

```
#include "Wall.h"

Wall::Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max)
    :cube(D3DXCOLOR(255, 20, 20, 255), min, max)
    ,boundingBox(min, max)
{
}

void Wall::Draw(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection)
{
    cube.Draw(matView, matProjection);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to, how would I write the initialisation syntax inside the constructor rather than using an initialiser list? also what are the benefit of the initialiser list? just clarity?

Comment: You can't run it inside the constructor body. Your objects are initialized in the initializer list. So if you don't do it there the compiler will use the default ctor. If it is not present you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make `cube` and `boundingBox` regular (non-pointer) class members, then use an initializer list to call the appropriate constructor for them, e.g.

```
Wall::Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max) :
  cube(D3DXCOLOR(255, 20, 20, 255), min, max),
  boundingBox(min, max)
{
   // nothing
}
```

Comment: am I right in thinking that if cube accepts no arguments you don't need to initialise it anywhere?

Comment: @SirYakalot: that's correct -- the default no-parameter constructor will be used if you don't specify a constructor using an initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is wrong when you work with pointers: `boundingBox = BoundingBox(min, max);` there should be a `new` before the `BoundingBox`.

You could simply adjust the declaration of the attributes inside the class:

```
class Wall
{
private:
    Cube cube;
    BoundingBox boundingBox;
public:
    Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max);
    ~Wall();
    void Draw(D3DXMATRIX matView, D3DXMATRIX matProjection);
};
```

Now you adjust your CTOR:

```
Wall::Wall(D3DXVECTOR3 min, D3DXVECTOR3 max) : cube(D3DXCOLOR(255, 20, 20, 255), min, max), boundingBox(min, max)
{ }
```